# How to add width/height to JavaScript command "onmouseover"

Tags: javascript, image, height, width, onmouseover

How can you add width/height inside the command `onmouseover`? example:

```
onMouseOver="if (document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps_3201302221606237').src= 'images/rhs2.png';"
onMouseOut="if (document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps_3201302221606237').src='images/high_schools.gif';">
```

When the mouse goes over a certain element, i need the image being displayed to have a certain width or height?

OK to give you a more clearer picture of what i am trying to accomplish, i have a picture that is static with different icons on it, each icon has a link on it based on coordinates it takes from the image, i want that when the mouse goes over the certain coordinates on the map for a the icon to get bigger or another image appear on top of the coordinates that is a little bit bigger than the icon on the static image so that it creates the effect that its making it bigger and when mouse goes out it dissapears the new picture, here is the code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q587j5nizg9r5m6/file.html

Comment: What have you attempted to accomplish what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

After `.src='images/rhs2.png` add

```
document.getElementById('the-id').style.height = certainHeight;
```

Do something similar for width.

I'd also strongly advise that you drop the `on` event attributes and use JavaScript for binding instead:

```
document.getElementById('Image-Maps_3201302221606237').addEventListener(
    'mouseover', function () {

    this.src = newSrc;
    this.style.height = certainHeight;
    this.style.width = certainWidth;
});
```

Comment: read my discription again i updated with more info, it doesnt work

Comment: i added a example file and shared it, i hope it helps you understand in what im trying to do so you can help me.

Comment: it doesnt work? i added more info in the discription about the problem